# Infinite loop when I try to redirect according to browser language

Tags: javascript

I am now learning JS and I try to redirect the visitor according to the language of the browser (if this is diferent to 'es' redirect to 'en') using the following script:

```
    var language = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

    if (language.indexOf('en') > -1) {
        document.location.href = 'https://example.com/en/';
        }
```

BUT this script is causing infinite loop and the page don't load correcly.

How to deal with this?

Comment: What about detecting `/en/` in the url and, only if it's not present, do what you're doing right now?

Comment: "BUT this script is causing infinite loop" — That would suggest that you are running the code on the page at `https://example.com/en/` … why would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply redirecting doesn't change the navigator language. So, even on `/en/` I'd expect it to try to redirect again.

You might want this:

```
var language = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

if (language.indexOf('en') > -1 && document.location.href.indexOf('/en/') !== -1) {
    document.location.href = 'https://example.com/en/';
}
```

Obviously, the code above is niave as there could be another occurrance of `/en/` in the url somewhere, but you get the idea :)

Comment: What about looking for `"/en/"`, so there are less chances it will collide, for example, with 'enlighted'?

Comment: @DavinTryon True. I get it. I will try different options for the /en/ Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
   window.location.href='http://example.com/en/'
```

Comment: Why? Is there some reason why using `document` to get to the location object would cause the problem described in the question? Have tested the two versions of the code and confirmed that the problem occurs with one but not the other? Or are you just throwing untested random guesses out as answers?

Comment: The same result.